# Converting timecodes

Tags: python, time, timecodes

Is there a way in python to convert timecodes, for example:

```
t1 = 00:05:08 in 24fps
==> What is t1 in 23.997 fps?
```

I basically want to convert from dropframe to non-dropframe and vice versa.

So far I have:

```
from timecode import Timecode
tc1 = Timecode('29.97', '00:04:22:04')
tc1. ?
```

Comment: The [Final Cut Pro](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=D%26section=6%26tasks=true) docs have some good stuff about this.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [timecode 0.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timecode/0.3.0)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes that's what I'm trying to figure out but the documentation is a little bit slight. Any idea how I'd use that to convert from one timecode to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have [`timecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timecode/0.3.0) installed, but I've been reading through the source and it looks like you have to do the following:

1. Create your initial `Timecode` object
2. Get the number of frames it contains with its `frames` attribute
3. Use that integer value to create a new `Timecode` object

It should look like this:

```
from timecode import Timecode

tc1 = Timecode('29.97', '00:04:22:04')
tc2 = Timecode('30', frames=tc1.frames)
```